# Unable to Edit New Keyframes

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I'm using version 2.79 of Blender and I can't edit my mesh to create an animation.

The Problem: [image: Blender Cannot Edit Mesh for Animation] I cannot edit my mesh when I create a new shape key (Key1). I can edit fine when I switch to the Basis key. When I try to scale the image in Key 1 a red line appears showing the axis I'm trying to scale but the vertices don't move.

The steps I took: Object mode > select object > create Basis shape key > create Key 1 > Edit mode > begin editing the object

I previously created an animation that worked so I'm pissed, extremely frustrated, and ready to jump off a bridge (smh, j/k of course). I've done too much work to start over. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Change the weight of Key 1 to be 
 - Full 1.0

The weight must be set to 1.0 to see the full effect.

The value is under the word Relative. It is in  the blender screen capture above.

Temporarily changing the eye icon next to a shape key name may help you to isolate the effects of a shape key and its weight.

Answer (score -1):

To fix I had to disable shape key in edit mode shown in the image. [image]